# Toggle back an action in JavaScript using classname

Tags: javascript, onclick, toggle

I have a JavaScript function `openWall();` which is set to add a class to a `div`. However, now I'd like to toggle back this action. I've done the function `closeWall();` in order to revert this action, however I don't know how to make the `div` recognize it.

The Script:

```
function openWall() {
  var wall;
  theWall = document.getElementById("wall");

  theWall.className = "menu-responsive";

  function closeWall() {
    theWall.className = "";
  }

}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="hamburger">
  <a href="#" onclick="openWall();">Menu</a>
</div>
<div id="wall"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to call an `openWall()`, or a `closeWall()`, function on clicking the element simply use a `toggleWall()` function to either open, or close, the relevant element based on its current state; which can be determined by looking for the class-name which denotes its open state (the absence of that class-name implies that the wall is not open). So, I'd suggest the following:

```
function toggleWall() {
  var theWall = document.getElementById('wall');

  if (theWall.className.indexOf('menu-responsive') > -1) {
    // indexOf returns -1 when the string is not found,
    // therefore 'theWall' is found if the index is
    // greater than -1; so 'theWall' is 'open', so here
    // we close it:
    theWall.className = theWall.className.replace('menu-responsive', '');
  } else {
    // the else here means that the string was not found,
    // returning an index of -1 (or, technically, -1 or less;
    // but indexOf only returns -1, 0 or positive indexes.
    // so the string was not found, means the 'theWall' is
    // 'closed' and so must be opened:
    theWall.className = theWall.className + ' menu-responsive';
  }
}
```

```js
function toggleWall() {
  var theWall = document.getElementById('wall');

  if (theWall.className.indexOf('menu-responsive') > -1) {
    theWall.className = theWall.className.replace('menu-responsive', '');
  } else {
    theWall.className = theWall.className + ' menu-responsive';
  }
}
```

```css
#wall {
  background-color: red;
  height: 4em;
}
#wall.menu-responsive {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
#wall::before {
  content: 'closed';
}
#wall.menu-responsive::before {
  content: 'open';
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger">
  <a href="#" onclick="toggleWall();">Menu</a>
</div>
<div id="wall"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p8cbt3cj/).

Or, using a slightly more up-to-date approach, you could simply use `Element.classList.toggle()` to add, or remove, the given class-name as appropriate:

```
function toggleWall() {
  var theWall = document.getElementById('wall');
  theWall.classList.toggle('menu-responsive');
}
```

```js
function toggleWall() {
  var theWall = document.getElementById('wall');

  // find out if the list of classes of the
  // Element contains the class-name of
  // 'menu-responsive' it's removed, and if
  // it is not present then it's added:
  theWall.classList.toggle('menu-responsive');
}
```

```css
#wall {
  background-color: red;
  height: 4em;
}
#wall.menu-responsive {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
#wall::before {
  content: 'closed';
}
#wall.menu-responsive::before {
  content: 'open';
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger">
  <a href="#" onclick="toggleWall();">Menu</a>
</div>
<div id="wall"></div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p8cbt3cj/1/).

Further, I'd strongly advise that you move away from the use of inline HTML attributes for event-binding. Switching to JavaScript-bound events makes for somewhat easier maintenance and updating without having to find-and-replace function calls littered throughout the HTML source. That said, I'd suggest using `EventTarget.addEventListener()` to add an event-handler:

```
document.querySelector('.hamburger > a[href="#"]')
  .addEventListener('click', toggleWall);

function toggleWall() {
  var theWall = document.getElementById('wall');
  theWall.classList.toggle('menu-responsive');
}
```

```js
// document.querySelector() returns the first
// HTML element matched by the CSS selector
// supplied as an argument; here it searches for
// an <a> element with a 'href' attribute equal
// to '#' which is the child of another element
// with the 'hamburger' class-name:
document.querySelector('.hamburger > a[href="#"]')

  // binds the 'toggleWall()' function as the
  // event-handler for the 'click' event:
  .addEventListener('click', toggleWall);

function toggleWall() {
  var theWall = document.getElementById('wall');
  theWall.classList.toggle('menu-responsive');
}
```

```css
#wall {
  background-color: red;
  height: 4em;
}
#wall.menu-responsive {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
#wall::before {
  content: 'closed';
}
#wall.menu-responsive::before {
  content: 'open';
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger">
  <a href="#">Menu</a>
</div>
<div id="wall"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you actually *call* the closeWall() function, or the code within doesn't get executed. Other than that, your code should work.

Aside from that, I'd suggest setting the .className back to whatever value it was before the change by saving that value in a variable.

Comment: I do that, however when called, the `closeWall()` avoid the `openWall()` to get executed when clicked.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the closeWall() avoid the openWall() to get executed", but I did notice that you've declared the closeWall() function itself inside of the openWall() function. Which means that, at the least, it's not even declared until openWall() is called. Possibly not even accessible outside of the scope of the openWall() function

Comment: I've set `onclick="openWall();` to the `<a>`. When clicking the Menu, the openWall() gets executed, so a class name will be added to a `div` with the `id="wall"`. Thats work nice, however, if I call the `closeWall();` (which is set to delete the class names) to get executed, the openWall understand run until it and the div id will not have any class!

Comment: The div isn't responding the way you want? What do you mean by "the openWall understand run until it"? Are you setting the proper variable? In your code it says "theWall.className" yet the variable "theWall" isn't declared in the code provided..JavaScript interprets that as a local variable declaration?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below to toggle class name

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="hamburger">
      <a href="#" onclick="toggleWall();">Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div id="wall"> wall </div>
    <script>
    function toggleWall() {
      var wall;
      theWall = document.getElementById("wall");

     if(theWall.className ==="abc"){
        theWall.className = "menu-responsive";
     }else{
        theWall.className = "abc";
    }

    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```